# How do I nest test descriptions?

Tags: casperjs

I want to integration test the skinning of a site so I'd like to iterate over a number of hostnames checking that all pages render, and the theme is functional.

I'm not having any luck nesting the way you start a casper test:

```
casper.test.begin(base.name, 5, function suite(test) { /* ... */ });
```

so how would I define sub-assertion description buckets like jasmine for instance?

Comment: Maybe a simple loog will work (not tested)

var host = ["url1", "url2", "url3" ];
for(var i= 0; i < host.length; i++)
{
     basename = host[i]

     casper.start(basename, function() {

     });
     casper.run(function() {
         this.test.done();
     });

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on casper documentation (http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each) :

```
var links = [
    'http://google.com/',
    'http://yahoo.com/',
    'http://bing.com/'
];

casper.start().each(links, function(self, link) {
    self.thenOpen(link, function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });
});

/**
 * You can write your test here
 */

/**
 * Running test
 */
casper.run();
```

Comment: that doesn't make the tests hierarchial in any sense. I can't nest descriptions such that site name has tests, some of which are in one bucket that has other buckets. This isn't actually a solution, just a way to do casper tests.